# Why the circular cross correlation values between two different images is higher than its values between an image and the same image?

Tags: image, image-processing, signal-processing, correlation, cross-correlation

I tried to perform circular cross correlation between two images using `cxcorr_fft` downloaded from [the FileExchange](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/43967-circular-cross-correlation-using-fft).

```
function [ h ] = cxcorr_fft( a,b )
%CXCORR_FFT Calculates the circular crosscorrelation of the two input 
%   vectors using the fft based method
%
% Author: Johannes Schmitz, Oct. 16, 2013
%         schmitz@ti.rwth-aachen.de

% zeropad to the same length M
if (length(a) < length(b))
c = [ a zeros(1,length(b)-length(a)) ];
d = b;
else
c = a;
d = [ b zeros(1,length(a)-length(b)) ];
end

% calculate crosscorrelation
e = fft(c);
f = fft(d);

g = f.*conj(e);

h = fftshift(ifft(g));

end
```

1-  I applied the function `cxcorr_fft` between the image and itself and this matrix is a part of the correlation result:

[image]

Whereas when I tried it between two different images, the correlation result is:

[image]

Then I performed cross correlation using the MATLAB function `crosscorr`.
For the first case, between the image and itself, the correlation result is:

[image]

and on the second case (different images) the cross correlation result is:

[image]

The results of cross correlation seem to be logic, unlike the circular cross correlation results. What is the error with the circular cross correlation code? Why the correlation values between two different images is higher than the correlation values between an image and the same image??

Answer (score 0):

The function you are using is meant for 1D inputs. It is computing the cross correlation between corresponding columns in `a` and `b`.

For images, replace class to `fft` with `fft2` (2D) or `fftn` (arbitrary dimensionality), and the call to `ifft` with `ifft2` or `ifftn`.

The zero-padding code is also incorrect for inputs that are not vectors, I would just remove it, assuming your images are of the same size already.

Do note that the magnitude of the values in the cross-correlation function are related to the magnitude in the input images. Computing the cross-correlation with an image that has very low values will lead to lower cross-correlation results than with an image with very large values. What matters is the shape of the cross-correlation function. There should be a peak, which indicates the shift for which the two images are most similar. This peak should be near the middle of the output, because you're using the `fftshift` operation.

Comment: I changed the function as you described                                                                     
      function [ h ] = cxcorr_fft( a,b )
      %CXCORR_FFT Calculates the circular crosscorrelation of the two input 
      %   vectors using the fft based method
      % calculate crosscorrelation
      e = fft2(a);
     f = fft2(b);

      g = f.*conj(e);

      h = fftshift(ifft2(g));

     end

and still the results not reasonable, there is no logical difference between circular cross corr. between the same image and between different images